# Поменять соседние цифры числа местами

Tags: c, инспекция-кода, int, арифметика

Сейчас разбираюсь вот с каким заданием (краткий пересказ):

> На вход дано целое число n. Преобразуйте его таким образом, чтобы две соседние цифры числа были поменяны местами.

То есть, у нас есть целое число n = *123456*, его необходимо преобразовать в число *214365*.

Вот мой код на C (код рабочий). Хотелось бы услышать критику со стороны насчет его эффективности. Что бы вы улучшили или предложили изменить? Потому что мне его надо будет сдать, а принимающий достаточно строгий)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int rewrite(int n) {
    
    int var_1, var_2;
    int n_new = 0;
    
    while (n >= 10) {     //Ставим условие >= 10 по причине того,
                          //что надо var_1 и var_2 присвоить по цифре
        var_1 = n % 10;   //То есть надо иметь в запасе как минимум десяток
        n /= 10;
        var_2 = n % 10;
        n /= 10;
        
        n_new *= 10;    //Записываем n_new таким образом, чтобы
        n_new += var_2; //соседние цифры были поменяны местами
        n_new *= 10;      
        n_new += var_1;
        
    }
    
    while (n_new != 0) { //Мы записывали число n_new при этом делили
                         //число n с конца, следовательно, его надо перевернуть
        n *= 10;
        n += n_new % 10;
        n_new /= 10;
        
    }
    
    return n;

}

int main() {
    
    int n;
    
    printf("Пожалуйста, введите число n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    printf("Обработанное число: %d\n", rewrite(n));
    
    return 0;  }
```

Comment: А Вам кроме умножения и деления что-то можно использовать? Например функцию логарифма?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов не желательно. На данный момент наc якобы учат строить "правильные и эффективные" алгоритмы (на самом же деле по большей части нас просто заставляют это делать xD). Когда я пытался делать предыдущее задание, то подключил библиотеку math, чтобы использовать извлечение из-под корня, за что получил по шее, и меня заставили все переписать, ха-ха. Соответственно, не хотелось бы использовать такие функции

Comment: Ну, Harry уже предложил отличное решение, не использующее логарифм

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Хорошо, спасибо)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

12345 во что должно превратиться? В 103254 или в 13254? И что делать с отрицательными числами?

Если считать, что в 103254, то я бы со скоростью ввода текста :) делал так:

```
unsigned int r2(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int m = 0;
    for(unsigned int e = 1;n;n/=100)
    {
        unsigned int d = n%100;
        d = (d%10)*10+d/10;
        m += d*e;
        e *= 100;
    }
    return m;
}
```

Если в 13254, то

```
unsigned int r2(unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int m = 0, e = 1;
    for(;n > 10;n/=100)
    {
        unsigned int d = n%100;
        d = (d%10)*10+d/10;
        m += d*e;
        e *= 100;
    }
    return m + n*e;
}
```

О критике...

Ну, например, `n_new *10;`, вероятно, должно быть `n_new *=10;`.

А еще введите число, скажем, 120304, и посмотрите, что получится :(

Comment: огромное спасибо. 

Насчет самого первого вопроса. Число 12345 должно превратиться в 13254. 

Во-вторых, мой код `n_new *10;` был опечаткой, вы правильно подметили, надо `n_new *= 10;`. 

Пытался ввести 120304 в мою программу, один ноль теряется) У вас же все в порядке. Спасибо еще раз!

Comment: Возник единственный вопрос по вашему коду. Зачем вам возвращать значение m + n*e, когда возврата простого m будет вроде как достаточным?

Comment: Возврат последней цифры, если их нечетное количество.

Comment: Все. До меня теперь все дошло. Спасибо!